# Use of managed object context in background and main thread

Tags: iphone, ios5, core-data

I have a function being called on click of button. Further there is method `[self getData]` called from this method , which updates values in db using core data.

Also, I have a background thread running which is executed after every one minute. I have used seperate managed object context and managed object notifications in the background threads. But I am not sure of whether to use a new managed object instance or `[self managedObjectContext]` in `[self getData]` as this method is called on main thread and do I have to use managed object notifications for this?

What is the best practice in these cases when there are methods running on background as well as main threads.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a temporary context, using a private queue concurrency type, that's a child of the main managed object context:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *temporaryContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
temporaryContext.parentContext = [self managedObjectContext];
[temporaryContext performBlock:^{
   // ...
}]
```

I found this tutorial very helpful when I was working how to do this:
http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/

Comment: thanx for your response i am checking it